# Нужно ли ставить запятую после сокращения слова?

Tags: запятые, сокращения

Возник вопрос, нужно ли ставить запятую после точки в сокращении слова?
Пример: "Прошу отправить материалы на эл., почту". Правильно ли это?

Comment: Если ответ решил проблему - можно отметить его галочкой (под нижним серым треугольником слева от ответа).

Comment: Только если "эл." означает "элеватор" - тогда это элемент перечисления, а не прилагательное при существительном. :)

Answer (score 1):

Не нужно. Это не правильно.
Раз запятой не было до сокращения, то и после она появиться не может:
*Прошу отправить материалы на электронную (запятой нет) почту.*

Если запятая была до сокращения, то она должна остаться.